# objective-c using an 'or'

Tags: objective-c

how to use and "or" or what you would call it

like:

```
    if (n1 'or' n2 'or' n3 'or' n4 'or' n5 == 1){
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symbol for 'or' in Objective-C is '||' so your statement would look like:

```
if((n1==1) || (n2==1) || (n3==1) || (n4==1) || (n5 == 1))
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: `==` takes precedence over `||` so technically the inner parentheses are unnecessary. Try `man operator` :)

Comment: also, if `n1` etc are boolean types, you also don't need `==1`, so this becomes `if ( n1 || n2 || n3 || n4 || n5 )`

Comment: @nielsbot, thanks I am aware of that (precedence), but years of programming experience has taught me that using parentheses to be explicit about what you mean is well worth it. I frequently find bugs where a programmer economized on parentheses, I have rarely found bugs caused by someone being explicit with them ;-)

Comment: Just gonna throw this out there in case its needed, but '&&' is AND.